# Nissan Tiida a/c airflow dries up after 45 mins

Tags: ac, nissan

I have a 2012 Nissan Tiida and the a/c works great at startup on all 4 speed settings.
I live in Dubai, and in summer (now) its 45C so its very hot outside. That being said the A/c is great... for about 30 mins. Then, slowly the a/c airflow starts reducing until it literally stops. The blower fan is still working, just nothing comes out of the vents.There is also a noticeable change in the sound, more like a deeper thrumming sound.If I turn off the airconditioning at this point, and wait a few minutes, the airflow will come back at a much reduced force, and after maybe 10-15 minutes again slowly stops... repeat repeat etc. we changed the filters twice recently, both times the ac worked perfectly afterwards for longer periods with no noticable drop in airflow for about a month each time, seemed like it was fixed... but now its come back.
AC gas levels have been checked and rechecked, all ok. Gas pipe from Compressor is still icy cold when problem occurs.
Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it aircon (which only has on/off switch) or full climate control? If the latter, perhaps the inside temperature has been lowered to the thermostat setting, and only needs a trickle of cold air to maintain it, against full blast to achieve it. Have you tried lowering the temperature setting to 'minimum'?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It could be the expansion valve. It allows too cold of air to go through the evaporator and freezes the condensation which will plug the evaporator with ice. This restricts air flow. When this happens by turning off the AC, the ice will melt. Then when you turn on the AC again it will blow cold air until it freezes up again.